# Vb Listbox to database

Tags: sql, .net

How can I copy the contents of a 2d list box to my database table?

The List box has 2 dimensions so I need to store it in a table with 2 columns

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: For people to help you better, I would add code to help give you a better answer